# How to add new in Build Action from a package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to add a new item/type under *Item* > Properties > "Build Action" from a package(i.e. nuget)

[image: Build Action screenshot]

I used Avalonia as a reference:

- [Item Schema File](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7842883961d094e08e9def7f30cf32fd573179c7/packages/Avalonia/AvaloniaItemSchema.xaml)
- [Avalonia.props](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7842883961d094e08e9def7f30cf32fd573179c7/packages/Avalonia/Avalonia.props)
- [Avalonia.target](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7842883961d094e08e9def7f30cf32fd573179c7/packages/Avalonia/Avalonia.targets)
- [AvaloniaBuildTasks.props](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7842883961d094e08e9def7f30cf32fd573179c7/packages/Avalonia/AvaloniaBuildTasks.props)
- [AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7842883961d094e08e9def7f30cf32fd573179c7/packages/Avalonia/AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets)
- [Avalonia.csproj](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7842883961d094e08e9def7f30cf32fd573179c7/packages/Avalonia/Avalonia.csproj)

I cut out a lot of unnecessary stuff, which left me with this:

- Project.props

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
      <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)PermissionsText.xml" />
      <AvailableItemName Include="PermissionsText" />
      <CompilerVisibleItemMetadata Include="AdditionalFiles" MetadataName="SourceItemGroup"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(EnableDefaultItems)'=='True'">
      <PermissionsText Include="**\*.ptxt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="_InjectAdditionalFiles" BeforeTargets="GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileShouldRun">
      <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Include="@(PermissionsText)" SourceItemGroup="PermissionsText" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

  </Project>
  ```
- Project.targets

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="**\*.ptxt" />
    </ItemGroup>

  </Project>
  ```
- Project.csproj

  ```xml
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
      <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
      <!-- Package Info -->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="3.9.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
      <Content Include="PermissionsText.xml">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>build\;buildTransitive\</PackagePath>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="PermissionsNodeGenerator.props">
          <Pack>true</Pack>
          <PackagePath>build\;buildTransitive\</PackagePath>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="PermissionsNodeGenerator.targets">
          <Pack>true</Pack>
          <PackagePath>build\;buildTransitive\</PackagePath>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

  </Project>
  ```
- The other project files are available [here](https://github.com/Arthri/PermissionsNodeGenerator/tree/1a03f58ae4e41139e246962e803817014f1bd4df)

I've been staring at this and Avalonia's code for hours, and I'm very sure they're similar, however I can't seem to figure out why Avalonia's types are appearing but mine aren't. From what I can tell, the most important part is `AvailableItemName` and `PropertyPageSchema`, both of which are present in the props file. I am also very sure the props file is very loaded. My project depends on additional files(defined in the same props file) and would crash with `InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements` if they weren't defined

After that, I came across this [guide](https://mmaitre314.github.io/2015/01/11/custom-content-type-in-visual-studio-projects.html) by mmaitre314. It put the `AvailableItemName` and `PropertyPageSchema` properties in the targets instead of props, I've tried doing that hoping it would work, however it still didn't appear under build action

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I apologize. I posted it on SoftwareEngineering mainly because it's more about configuration and deployment rather than actual programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, or how, or what but: I deleted my local copy of the project, cloned it from the provided GitHub link, rebuilt it and re-referenced it, and it works now.

I had a few speculations why it might've not worked though all of them seem to be false:

- Source Generators/Analyzers can't define their own content types/build actions. Removing the analyzer part didn't help
- I was testing it on a .NET Core 3.1 project but it was a .NET Standard 2.0 Source Generator. Retargetting either project to match didn't help
- The schema file, props, and/or targets files are formatted incorrectly. Checked them about more than 10 times now and I'm very sure that's not the issue
- The test project's `.vs` or `obj` folder was caching an old version of the project where it didn't have custom types. I've deleted them though it didn't help, furthermore, rebuilding from an exact copy on GitHub works, just not my local copy
- The project's name is too long/badly formatted(I'm getting desperate here). Also wrong, created a project with the name `ClassLibrary1LONGNAMESourceGenerator` (included numbers to be sure), copied the files over, and rebuilt it. Worked, so the name is not the issue
- Several other crazy guesses

Thanks for all the help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work. Did some tests, and it seems we need to do something or wait for some time to let it display(delay? Maybe).

[image]

It is hard to say which step matters or make it work, but I did do these things:

**1).** Right-clicked the project(test project) > Unload Project > right-clicked it again > Reload Project.

**2).** Closed project(test project) and then reopened it.

**3).** Created a `.ptxt` file and included it into the project. Excluded it and then included again.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. How did you reference the analyzer? I built as a nupkg and then placed it in a folder and added that folder as a nuget source then installed it. For some reason that doesn't work for me. However if I reference it as a project instead, it does work, but I want to ship it as a nupkg, not as a project